# Xamarin.Forms setting IsVisible doesn't trigger before function is done.

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms project I have a login form that logs in the user and then redirects them to another page. I want to show an ActivityIndicator while it attempts to login, but setting IsVisible to true doesn't actually take effect before the login function is done. My code looks like this:

```
void OnLoginButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadingIndicator.IsVisible = true;
    Login();
}

public void Login()
{
    var user = new User
    {
        Email = usernameEntry.Text,
        Password = passwordEntry.Text
    };

    User validUser = AreCredentialsCorrect(user);
    if (validUser != null)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new ProfilePage());
    }
    else
    {
        messageLabel.Text = "Login failed";
        passwordEntry.Text = string.Empty;
        //It will only show the LoadingIndicator at this point.
    }
}
```

If the user is correct, it never shows the LoadingIndicator because it navigates to another page before it can show it.
If the user is invalid, it will only show the LoadingIndicator after it hits the else clause and shows the "Login failed". Can anyone figure why that is, and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Async calls and await the main block of operations. If anything you want to update/change in UI, do it using `BeginInvokeOnMainThread`.

```
    void OnLoginButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadingIndicator.IsVisible = true;
            await Login();
        }

        public async void Login()
        {
            await Task.Run(() => {
            var user = new User
            {
                Email = usernameEntry.Text,
                Password = passwordEntry.Text
            };

             User validUser = AreCredentialsCorrect(user);
            }).ContinueWith((a) => SomeMethod(validUser));
        }

         public void SomeMethod()
         {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
             if (validUser != null)
             {
                Navigation.PushAsync(new ProfilePage());
             }
             else
             {
                messageLabel.Text = "Login failed";
                passwordEntry.Text = string.Empty;
                //It will only show the LoadingIndicator at this point.
             }
           }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using async/await. Allow the UI to update while also navigating.

```
async void OnLoginButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadingIndicator.IsVisible = true;
    await Login();
}

public async Task Login()
{
    var user = new User
    {
        Email = usernameEntry.Text,
        Password = passwordEntry.Text
    };

    User validUser = AreCredentialsCorrect(user);
    if (validUser != null)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ProfilePage());
    }
    else
    {
        messageLabel.Text = "Login failed";
        passwordEntry.Text = string.Empty;
        //It will only show the LoadingIndicator at this point.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible explanations here one it could be redirecting so fast that it doesn't have time to display the loadingindicator, I have experienced this problem before. We had a really nice loading symbol and animation but then we switched to Aurelia framework and it logs in so fast it just doesn't have time to display it even though it was actually working. As for code changes I would try to add it into the login function as well at least for right now to give some clarity to if its actually just logging in so fast its not displayed or its just not displaying at all. Her is my suggestion.

```
void OnLoginButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadingIndicator.IsVisible = true;
    Login(LoadingIndicator.IsVisible);
}

public void Login(Bool IsVisible)<--- might have type wrong not familiar with you custom defines types I would expect it to be a bool though.
IsVisible = true;
{
    var user = new User
    {
        IsVisible = true;
        Email = usernameEntry.Text,
        Password = passwordEntry.Text
    };

    User validUser = AreCredentialsCorrect(user);
    if (validUser != null)
    {
        IsVisible = true;
        Navigation.PushAsync(new ProfilePage());
    }
    else
    {
        IsVisible = true;
        messageLabel.Text = "Login failed";
        passwordEntry.Text = string.Empty;
        //It will only show the LoadingIndicator at this point.
    }
}
```

If nothing else this might help clarify why it isn't being displayed. Also don't forget to use the web debugger f12 by default on most browsers and look for the element that will contain the Indicator.

Hope this helps! If not let me know and I'll remove the answer(I had to use an answer because I can't comment under 50 rep) Cheers!